# InstallUtil.exe - Unable to load Assembly on x64

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to install my Windows Service which I can compile in x86 or x64. If I install the x86 binaries using the following line then, the service is installed

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>installutil.exe "D:\PathToBin\bin\Release\MyWindowsService.exe"
```

**PROBLEM:** I need to compile my code in x64 and need to install the service in x64 configuration. For this, I am trying to install the service using x64 InstallUtil.exe and therefore, I run the following:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>installutil.exe "D:\PathToBin\bin\x64\Release\MyWindowsService.exe"
```

The above line throws the following error:

> M: OnBeforeInstall
>
> Can not create installer of type MyWindowsService.WindowsServiceInstaller
>
> M: OnBeforeRollback
>
> Unable to load assembly

Comment: Examine Windows Event log. If there is a 32 bit dll somewhere under the same name, it can be trying to load it. If that's the case then you'll be able to see exactly what dll is loaded incorrectly in the events.

Comment: `MyWindowsService.InstallLog` exists only inside `bin/Release` but there is not install log inside `bin\x64\Release`.

Comment: @HansPassant : I have checked the Project>Properties>Build (VS2010) and `Platform Target` is already set to `x64`. I didn't see any option called `Prefer 32-Bit` there.